# Как получить base64 из файла в с++?

Tags: c++, base64

Я открываю файл с помощью std::ifstream в бинарном режиме и объявляю поток:

`std::ifstream file_stream("D://123.png", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);`

`std::stringstream img_base64;`

Как мне получить base64 из картинки в мой поток?

Comment: Использовать криптографическую библиотеку. Поищи на github. https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=base64&type=Repositories

Comment: @megorit, а есть пример использования, какой-либо из этих библиотек?

Comment: @megorit, Я использую код вида    
```std::ifstream file_stream("D://123.png", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
char* buffer = new char[file_stream.tellg()];
file_stream.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
img_base64<< base64_encode(buffer, sizeof(buffer));```
И он работает не корректно.(Библиотека https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-base64)

Comment: @КириллЕпифанов Нестоит юзать new просто так, особенно там где этого совсем ненужно делать. Если данные бинарны, то стоит взять vector<byte>, а не делать char*. Помню в 1 либе попытались померять размер такой строки с strlen...

Comment: @КириллЕпифанов ну а чего вы ожидали - вы же считываете уже находясь в конце файла...

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков не спорю, что лучше пользоваться контейнерами, нежели вручную выделять и освобождать память руками, но не совсем понятно к чему вы привели strlen?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch к тому, что raw указатели зло. В данном случае найдётся кто-то попытавшийся считать char* как строку и конечно же измерит её длину. использовать сначала std::ifstream а потом char* buffer, выглядит глупо.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков слишком уж радикальное заявление про указатели... Тоесть, если у меня функция `int foo(std::string &str, size_t *len)` то она плохая, потому что сдесь используется указатель?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Да откудаж мне знать, по одной сигнатуре этого не определить. Просто есть те кого устраивают сегфолты, и те, кого нет.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков во-первых вы сами написали про что raw указатели это зло - никто за язык вас не тянул. В сигнатуре функции - raw указатель, значит либо функция априори плохая, либо raw указатели не могут быть априори плохие. Во-вторых, святая наивность))) посмеялся с вашего утверждения про сегфолты. Увы, но они объясняются не использованием указателей, а кривыми руками)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Получить сегфолт без указателей гораздо труднее. И да они однозначно плохие, но есть исключения 1) когда без них не обойтись в интерфейсе либы(но так как есть std::string это не такой случай) 2) когда на решение задачи без указателей может потребоваться неоправданно много времени.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков мне просто интересно, а какой у вас опыт в програмировании на с++ для подобных заявлений? По мне - так это просто абсурд

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117820/discussion-between---and-andrej-levkovitch).